# convert integer to decimal or float with 8 numbers in precision

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, decimal

say I have this big number 1956787654321 and I want to convert it to float with the decimal point 8 numbers in like so 19567.87654321.

How would I do this in python?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```py
>>> 1956787654321 /10**8
19567.87654321
```

Comment: `10**8` is technically correct but does an unnecessary calculation.

Answer (score 2):

To get an `8` point precision float, you can devide your `integer` by `1e8` :

```
1956787654321 / 1e8
# 19567.87654321
```

Comment: omg thanks for the fast response, I didn't think of dividing the number :S